# How to check Database connection and credentials using laravel tinker

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, tinker

Check database credentials using tinker in a laravel 6.x application

- What is the command to check Database connection in tinker in a laravel application

Answer (score 1):

To run tinker:

```
php artisan tinker
```

Then run:

```
DB::select('SHOW TABLES');
```